# What criteria should I think about as I evaluate UK trading platforms?

Tags: united-kingdom, investing

I'm totally new to investing, and I'm looking to invest in some index tracker funds. Currently I have little idea about what to look for in an investment platform.

For example, does HSBC's Investment Centre seem to offer good value with these terms:

- 0% initial charge
- 0.39% Account Fee when investing in clean share class funds
- Annual management fees of each fund invested in

(https://investments.hsbc.co.uk/product/206/investing-in-funds-online)

Is there more information I should be considering?

Roughly what would be considered good initial charges, account fees and management fees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Use a comparison website to compare features and the fees associated.](http://www.money.co.uk/share-dealing/all-share-dealing.htm)
- Always read the fine print, however enticing the service might be. Look for inactivity fees, hidden charges and stuff like that.
- [Try going for stock and share ISAs which are tax friendly upto £11520(till 04/2014).](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/ISA-guide-savings-without-tax)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good website with information about investing platforms: http://monevator.com/compare-uk-cheapest-online-brokers/.